# change image source based on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the image source for devices with small screen size.
I want to target only mobile devices (not desktop browsers) smaller than 1024px width.

I don't want to use media queries since they are going to load both hi and low resolution versions of the image if I change the browser size on desktop. I can target devices separately but it's gonna be huge mess on my css file.

Any proper solution to load smaller images for mobile devices only? (especially smaller than tablets). Also with userAgent it's not easy to target devices like android tablets and android smartphones.

I am using this code but it also causes duplicate file load after I refresh the page.

```
$(function() {
  if($(window).width() <= 1024) {
    $(".slides-container li img").each(function() {
      $('.slides-container li img').attr('src',function(i,e){
        return e.replace("img/galeri/large","img/galeri/medium");
      });
    });
   }
});
```

Comment: Instead of modifying the `src` attribute, you can try inserting the img element dynamically using `$().html()`

Answer (score 2):

Try doing an event handler for window resize:

```
<body onload="window.addEventListener('resize', setPanels); setPanels();">

function setPanels()
{
  var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  if(windowWidth < 500)
  {
    document.getElementById('your image').src = 'new image source';
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById('your image').src = 'new image source desktop';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  if($(window).width() <= 1024) {
    $(".slides-container li img").each(function() {
      if($(this).attr('src').indexOf("large") > -1){
          $(this).attr('src',function(i,e){
               return e.replace("img/galeri/large","img/galeri/medium");
          });
      }
    });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue (as I understand it) is that when the page initially loads, all the images have `src="img/galeri/large/..."`, and you're trying to conditionally change that to be instead `src="image/galeri/medium/..."` if appropriate for the viewport's width.

Unfortunately, as soon as the `img` is loaded in the dom, the browser will begin to load the src file, all before your jQuery ever runs.

Given that you evidently have some control over the backend, the lightest weight (albeit quite hacky) solution may be to nuke the `src` attribute on all `img`s  on the page, replaced with some other attribute `isrc` that contains the asset name (the bit after the `img/galeri/large` or `img/galeri/medium`), and then step through your image tags on page load like this

```
$(function() {
    var assetLoc = "img/galeri/large";
    if($(window).width() <= 1024) {
        assetLoc = "img/galeri/medium";
    }

    $(".slides-container li img").each(function() {
        var assetSrc = assetLoc + $(this).attr('isrc');
        $(this).attr('src', assetSrc);
    });
});
```

Again, hacky, but it will allow for the asynchronous loading you're looking for with a minimal amount of work.